# Rails console and rake test:units

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, console

I was wondering whether I could run my tests under rails console rather than the command line. 
Actually the rationale for this is that rake test:units on the command line takes ages to load the rails environment. So I thought, why not start a console to load the environment once and then keep running rake unit:tests each time I wanted to check my code. After all, rails is meant to be agile and promote agile development. So I tried this. First of all I had to say:

require 'Rake'

but even after doing that I got the error message:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rake::Task['test.units'].invoke
RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'test.units'
```

I guess I need to somehow tell it where to look. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 5):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'rake'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > r = Rake.application
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > r.init
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > r.load_rakefile
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > r['test:units'].invoke
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked the first time (but actually still took ages to run) and then returned nil when I tried running r['test:units'].invoke again. I think I'll look at Spork.

Comment: Actually, adding r.clear allows me to repeat r.load_rakefile and r['test:units'].invoke again. The time to run this on my computer was reduced from 80 seconds (rake on command line) to 25 seconds, and so a substantial improvement, although still quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

A better idea is to use Spork to keep the environment loaded and then autotest to run tests automatically when files change.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the way to go. However, I am using RoR in a small uni module and didn't want to have to talk about rspec and other things not covered by the Agile Software Development with Rails book. I wonder whether the core rails bundle should switch to spork etc. It seems a little odd that it is still including testing technology that is too slow for TDD.